# Decomposition of joint distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I would like know if this is ok:

$$P(X\leq x,Y \leq y)= P(Y\leq y)-P(Y\leq y,X>x)$$

Why? Is this equivalent to (in the case of single distributions):

$$ P(X\leq x)= 1-P(X>x)? $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Pr(Y\leq y ) = Pr(Y\leq y , X\leq x) + Pr(Y\leq y , X> x)$$

By rearranging the above equality you will arrive at your expression.

This is in the same spirit as

$$ 1 = Pr(Y\leq y) + Pr(Y>y)$$

Basically, both equation "decomposed" probability of an "event" into sum of probabilities of mutually exclusive events.

Comment: Thanks, perfect!

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}\Pr(X\le x, Y\le y) &= \Pr(Y\le y)\Pr(X\le x|Y\le y)\\[1ex]& = \Pr(Y\le y)\,(1 - \Pr(X> x|Y\le y))\\[1ex]&=\Pr(Y\le y)-\Pr(X>x, Y\le y)\end{align}$